# RDS MySQL top CPU queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds, monitoring

I'd like to know if there is any way to get the top queries in my instance per CPU. I would see which query has more impact in my instance based on CPU usage.

Anyone have any idea if it possible in MySQL like SQL Server?

How can I get in real-time an event on MySQL which is reading million of lines, the information which appears on performance insight (AWS tool) shows a query which is very fast and returns a maximum of 573 lines.

Something useful like this:
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/07/29/sql-server-ssms-top-queries-by-cpu-and-io/

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved using [Idera Real-Time](http://wiki.idera.com/display/SQLDMYSQL/Real-Time):

> Real-Time continuously executes a bunch of queries on a server and fetches information on the top queries, tables, databases, user, hosts, queries that are locked, queries that are locking, etc. Since the information is retrieved in real time, you get to see what your server is up to at any point in time.

> Real-Time monitoring can be done in two modes: Processlist and Performance Schema.
>
> - Processlist mode, SQL DM for MySQL executes the query SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST every second to fetch the queries. Performance schema based Real-time makes use of the performance_schema database of the MySQL server. Performance schema database logs each and every query in its table. SQL DM for MySQL queries the performance_schema and retrieves the queries, including the short-lived ones.
> - Performance schema based Real-time, you can get extra information like Number of full table scans done by the query, Success, Error, and Warning count for each query.

Comment: Thanks Paul White


Sorry for a so poor answer.
I will be better in the next one.

Answer (score 0):

The slowlog is the best tool for capturing "slow" queries.

"per CPU" does not make sense.  A query might be running in CPU-0 for a while, them move to CPU-4, etc.

Use `pt-query-digest` is a good tool for summarizing the info.  More:  http://localhost/rjweb/mysql/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

The `SHOW PROCESSLIST` is likely to miss fast, but frequent queries.  Ditto for using the slowlog with `long_query_time` set too high.  (Recommend starting with `1`.)

Things like "full table scans" are only partially useful.  For example, if a table has only 10 rows, that flag is bogus.